# Where does vcpkg looks for Visual Studio Build tools installation?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, powershell, vcpkg

Following [How to install Visual Studio Build Tools unattended?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73341154/how-to-install-visual-studio-build-tools-unattended/) I installed Visual Studio Build Tools with:

```
# Visual Studio build tools
Write-Host "Installing visual studio build tools..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

cd $env:USERPROFILE

$exePath = "$env:TEMP\vs.exe"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_BuildTools.exe -UseBasicParsing -OutFile $exePath

Write-Host "layout..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

Start-Process $exePath -ArgumentList "--layout .\vs_BuildTools --quiet" -Wait
cd vs_BuildTools

Write-Host "actual installation..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

Start-Process vs_setup.exe -ArgumentList "--installPath $env:USERPROFILE\vs_BuildTools2022 --nocache --wait --noUpdateInstaller --noWeb --allWorkloads --includeRecommended --includeOptional --quiet --norestart" -Wait
```

You can see that I installed locally so I don't need admin permissions.

When I try to install something with vcpkg, however, it can't find my Visual Studio Build Tools installation:

```
Write-Host "Installing vcpkg..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git C:\src\vcpkg

C:\src\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat

C:\src\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe --version
C:\src\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe install gtest
```

gives

```
 error: in triplet x64-windows: Unable to find a valid Visual Studio instance
```

Is there some variable that I can set so `vcpkg` can find the Visual Studio Build Tools local installation?

Comment: I don't think the build tools alone are enough: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/pull/314

Answer (score 0):

You can use set [VCPKG_VISUAL_STUDIO_PATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/config-environment#vcpkg_visual_studio_path) in the triplet ( or via `--x-cmake-args=-DVCPKG_VISUAL_STUDIO_PATH=<yourpath>` for testing -> deactivates binary caching)

also running vcpkg with `--debug` might help to deduce why some found installations got rejected.

Answer (score 0):

first of all vcpkg lookup your installed vs versions here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_Instances